# swift, showing one alert then another in the same view

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to show a loading indicator while loading the data:

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Updating data", message: "Please wait...", preferredStyle: .alert)

            alert.view.tintColor = UIColor.black
            let loadingIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView = UIActivityIndicatorView(frame: CGRect(x: 10,y: 5,width: 50, height: 50)) as UIActivityIndicatorView
            loadingIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
            loadingIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.gray
            loadingIndicator.startAnimating();

            alert.view.addSubview(loadingIndicator)
            self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Then if the data loading is completed, I want to show another alert telling the user that the data is completed:

```
if dataLoaded{
    //dismiss the previous alert then show the new one
    dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
    let alert2 = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "Data has been updated", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
    alert2.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
    self.present(alert2, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

The 2nd alert never gets shown, any thought. I'm fairly new to swift

Thanks in advance 
BT

Comment: Place a breakpoint at `if dataLoaded` and make sure that condition is satisfied to call your alert.

Comment: I stepped through the code it executed the alert2 lines but I still don't see the 2nd alert. Is it because i can't use 2 alerts in the same view?

Comment: Try adding the code to show the second alert in the completion block when dismissing the first alert. The dismissal of the first alert is probably in progress when you are trying to present the second alert.

Comment: Won't calling `dismiss()` dismiss the View Controller, not the alert?

Comment: Where is this code starting with `if dataLoaded { ` being called?

Comment: adding the alert2 code in the completion code solved it. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

Use completion block to show next alert. Try this code, this is working.

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Updating data", message: "Please wait...", preferredStyle: .alert)

    alert.view.tintColor = UIColor.black
    let loadingIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView = UIActivityIndicatorView(frame: CGRect(x: 10,y: 5,width: 50, height: 50)) as UIActivityIndicatorView
    loadingIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
    loadingIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.gray
    loadingIndicator.startAnimating();

    alert.view.addSubview(loadingIndicator)

    self.present(alert, animated: true) {
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: { 
            let alert2 = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "Data has been updated", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
            alert2.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
            self.present(alert2, animated: true, completion: nil)
        })
    }
```

Comment: I tested this, It is working. And here I used completion of dismiss to show another alert. So It will work.

Comment: What if I have 100 alerts?